# How to evaluate a defun with square brackets in column 0 of its docstring?

Tags: functions, eval, doc-strings, defun

I have problems running `eval-defun` for a `defun` when there is a square bracket `[` in column 0 of its doc string. For example:

```el
(defun test ()
  "Test function. 
[Some text]"
  (message "Hello"))
```

When I position the cursor inside the function above and type `M-x eval-defun RET` it displays `"[Some text]"` in the echo area, but the `defun` is not being evaluated. If I remove the square bracket `[` in the doc string, and then reevaluate, it works fine and displays `"test"` in the echo area.

I am using GNU Emacs 25.2.1 on Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. Don't have a way to verify this, but what happens if you replace `[` with `\133`?

Comment: Just insert a backslash \ before the opening square bracket `[`. See [`(emacs) Left Margin Paren`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Left-Margin-Paren.html).

Comment: @Basil Thanks for the link. That seems to be the case, but I wonder why has a bracket in the first column the same effect as a parenthesis for `eval-defun`? A bracket in the first column cannot be the start of a `defun`, am I right?

Comment: It cannot be the start of a call to the `defun` macro, but it can be a top-level definition, which is what Emacs documentation refers to as a `defun`. See [`(emacs) Defuns`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Defuns.html). Note also that the documentation is careful to prefer the word "delimiter" to "paren", implying multiple paren-like characters.

Comment: What @Basil said. A "defun" in this context is not necessarily a call to Lisp macro `defun`.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIU fixing this would require a hack around of SPECPDL_INDEX in C-source.

However, `ar-backward-defun`,`ar-forward-defun` jumps to start and end of a `defun` also in these cases: https://github.com/andreas-roehler/thingatpt-utils-core/blob/master/ar-subr.el

Wherefrom a command to escape opening parens in column 0 might be provided:

```
(defun ar-auto-escape ()
  (interactive "*")
  (save-excursion
    (ar-beginning-of-defun)
    (let ((end (save-excursion (ar-end-of-defun) (line-beginning-position))))
      (forward-line 1) 
      (while (and (re-search-forward "^\\([\[(]+\\)" nil t 1) (< (line-beginning-position) end))
    (replace-match (concat "\\\\" (match-string-no-properties 1)))))))
```